# What is the different between voidEval and parseAndEval in RConnection?

Tags: java, r

I saw the method used to execute R function call and return the response.
we passing the query with schema to `parseAndEval` and passing `Rscript` files to `voidEval`.
The `parseAndEval` response to convert the  org.rosuda.REngine.RList

The code:

```
  RConnection rConn = new RConnectionManager().getRConnection();
  rConn.voidEval(scriptPath);
  RList rFunctionResponse = rConn.parseAndEval(query).asList();
```

I got the exception for `"eval failed, request status: error code: 127"`

How to fix it and explain what is different between both.

Answer (score 1):

**voidEval**

```
public void voidEval(java.lang.String cmd)
              throws RserveException
```

> evaluates the given command, but does not fetch the result (useful for
>   assignment operations)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> cmd - command/expression string
>
> **Throws:**
>
> RserveException

**parseAndEval**

```
    public REXP parseAndEval(java.lang.String cmd) throws   REngineException,
     REXPMismatchException    
convenince method equivalent to eval(parse(text, false), where, resolve);
```

**Parameters:**

> text - to parse
>
> where - environment to evaluate in
>
> resolve - whether to resolve the resulting reference or not
>
> **Returns:**
>
> result
>
> **Throws:**
>
> REngineException REXPMismatchException

**You need to add more details or code to check why this error is coming and on which line.**

Comment: Thanks for your response.